# sqlstate 42s22 column not found 1054 unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Mates, im getting error `sqlstate 42s22 column`activity_post_comments`not found 1054 unknown column in 'field list'`

But this column name exists in my database.

I have checked my database and i have checked for spelling mistakes but im still getting this error

```
public function storecomments(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Create Comment
    $activity_post = new ActivityPost;
    $activity_post->activity_post_comments = $request->input('activity_post_comments');
    $activity_post->activity_post_id = $id;
    $activity_post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $activity_post->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Comment Added');
}
```

Not sure why im getting this error so i cant save this values in my database

Model:

```html
class ActivityPostComment extends Model
{
 use SoftDeletes;

    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'activity_post_comments';
    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ActivityPost');
    }
}
```

[image: Database Table]

Comment: put your table structure too

Comment: @GauravGupta added

Comment: Have you try with some default data instead of $request->input('activity_post_comments');?

Comment: @DsRaj yep tried, still getting the same error

Comment: you prolly haven't defined it in your model, but since you haven't posted it yet, im just guessin

Comment: dd($activity_post) after this line $activity_post = new ActivityPost;

Comment: Add the model file

Comment: @DsRaj added model

Comment: @Ghost added model

Comment: @RajveerSingh not sure but your table name and column name are same that might be an issue.

Comment: @GauravGupta i have another table name called "comments" with column name "comments" and that worked perfectly.

Comment: @RajveerSingh your calling wrong model your model class name is "ActivityPostComment" while you are using "ActivityPost"

Comment: @GauravGupta OH RIGHT! THANKS YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @RajveerSingh any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above code that you have posted . your calling wrong model your model class name is

> ActivityPostComment

while you are using

> ActivityPost